# Django Master/Detail

Tags: django

I am designing a master/detail solution for my app. I have searched for ever in the django docs, also here and elsewhere I could, so I guess the answer is not that obvious, despite being an answer many people look for - not only in django, but in every language, I think.

Generally, in most cases, the master already exists: for example, the Django Docs illustrate the Book example, where we already have an Author and we want to add several Books for that Author.

In my case, the parent is not yet present on the database think of a purchase order, for instance.

I have thought to divide the process in two steps: the user would start to fill in the info for the master model (regular form) and then proceed to another view to add the lines (inline formset). But I don't think this is the best process at all - there are a lot of possible flaws in it.

I also thought about creating a temporary parent object in a different table and only having a definitive master when the children are finally created. But it still doesn't look clean.

Because of that, for my app it would be ideal to create the master object at the same time as the detail objects (lines) - again, like an order.

Is there a way where I can have the same view to manage both master and detail? Like this I would receive both in the same POST request and it would make a lot more sense, not to say it would be much cleaner.

Sorry if it's too long, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Django does not care about what order you create your master and view. You can create both in the same view or in separate views, django doesn't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that in my case the process could actually be split in two phases.
For this I simply use the traditional model form and inline formset.

But! I also found out that there could be several answers to this:

1. We could get crazy and build some spaceship in AJAX that would get the job done, simply by sending a JSON object (in which the lines could be an array of objects)
2. Django also has its ways and it's possible to send multiple forms in the same request! (thank you @mousetail for the tip).

Of course, be there as it may, there are many ways to build a house, these are just the ones I found out.